# min of given keys from python defaultdictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I got a `defaultdict` with lists as values and tuples as keys (`ddict` in the code below). I want to find the min and max of values for a given set of keys. The keys are given as a numpy array. The numpy array is a 3D array containing the keys. Each row of the 3D array is the block of keys for which we need to find the `min` and `max` i.e. for each row we take the corresponding 2D array entries, and get the values corresponding to those entries and find the `min` and `max` over those values. I need to do it for all the rows of the 3D array.

```
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np

ddict =  {(1.0, 1.0): [1,2,3,4], (1.0, 2.5): [2,3,4,5], (1.0, 3.75): [], (1.5, 1.0): [8,9,10], (1.5, 2.5): [2,6,8,19,1,31], (1.5,3.75): [4]}
indA = np.array([ [ [( 1.0, 1.0), ( 1.0, 3.75)], [(1.5,1.0), (1.5,3.75)] ], [ [(1.0, 2.5), (1.5,1.0)], [(1.5, 2.5), (1.5,3.75)] ] ], dtype='float16,float16')

mins = min(ddict, key=itemgetter(*[tuple(i) for b in indA for i in b.flatten()]))
maxs = max(ddict, key=itemgetter(*[tuple(i) for b in indA for i in b.flatten()]))
```

I tried the above code to get the output of

`min1 = min([1,2,3,4,8,9,10,4])` & `min2 = min([2,3,4,5,8,9,10,2,6,8,19,1,31,4])` and
`max1= max([1,2,3,4,8,9,10,4])` & `max2 = max([2,3,4,5,8,9,10,2,6,8,19,1,31,4])`

I want to calculate the `min` and `max` for every 2D array in the numpy array.  Any workaround ? Why my code is not working ? It gives me error `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Comment: "I want to find the min and max of a given set of keys" - do you mean to say that, for each set (or rather list, it seems) of tuples, you want to know the minimum across all lists associated with those tuple keys? Can you explain how that relates to the output you say you expected to get? (also, there is probably a parenthesis missing in your example output, but since I don't understand what your output should mean, I didn't correct it myself)

Comment: @Grismar i edited the question. What I mean is , they keys of the dictionary (tuples) is the entries of the 2D array (each row of the 3D array). I want to combine the values of the ddict for for each row of the 3D array (we need to combine the values corresponding to 4 keys, as we got a 2*2 array) and find the min and max.  I need to do it for all the rows of the 3D array. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense - see the answer below. Feel free to comment if that's somehow now what you needed though.

Comment: @Grismar, the code works on the input data I provided but not on my real code. I realized that I made a big mistake when I pasted the code. I forgot to make the array a structured array.  When I use your code on the new data I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'writeable void-scalar'`

Comment: I've had a look and updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think you're after:

```
import numpy as np

# I've reformatted your example data, to make it a bit clearer
# no change in content though, just different whitespace
# whether d is a dict or defaultdict doesn't matter
d = {
    (1.0, 1.0): [1, 2, 3, 4],
    (1.0, 2.5): [2, 3, 4, 5],
    (1.0, 3.75): [],
    (1.5, 1.0): [8, 9, 10],
    (1.5, 2.5): [2, 6, 8, 19, 1, 31],
    (1.5, 3.75): [4]
}

# indA is just an array of indices, avoid capitals in variable names
indices = np.array(
    [
        [[(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 3.75)], [(1.5, 1.0), (1.5, 3.75)]],
        [[(1.0, 2.5), (1.5, 1.0)], [(1.5, 2.5), (1.5, 3.75)]]
    ])

for group in indices:
    # you flattened each grouping of indices, but that flattens
    # the tuples you need intact as well:
    print('not: ', group.flatten())
    # Instead, you just want all the tuples:
    print('but: ', group.reshape(-1, group.shape[-1]))

# with that knowledge, this is how you can get the lists you want
# the min and max for
for group in indices:
    group = group.reshape(-1, group.shape[-1])
    values = list(x for key in group for x in d[tuple(key)])
    print(values)

# So, the solution:
result = [
    (min(vals), max(vals)) for vals in (
        list(x for key in grp.reshape(-1, grp.shape[-1]) for x in d[tuple(key)])
        for grp in indices
    )
]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
not:  [1.   1.   1.   3.75 1.5  1.   1.5  3.75]
but:  [[1.   1.  ]
 [1.   3.75]
 [1.5  1.  ]
 [1.5  3.75]]
not:  [1.   2.5  1.5  1.   1.5  2.5  1.5  3.75]
but:  [[1.   2.5 ]
 [1.5  1.  ]
 [1.5  2.5 ]
 [1.5  3.75]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 2, 6, 8, 19, 1, 31, 4]
[(1, 10), (1, 31)]
```

That is, `[(1, 10), (1, 31)]` is the result you are after, `1` being the minimum of the combined values of the first group of indices, `10` the maximum of that same group of values, etc.

Some explanation of key lines:

```
values = list(x for key in group for x in d[tuple(key)])
```

This constructs a list of combined values by looping over every pair of key values in `group` and using them as an index into the dictionary `d`. However, since key will be an `ndarray` after the reshaping, it is passed to the `tuple()` function first, so that the `dict` is correctly indexed. It loops over the retrieved values and adds each value `x` to the resulting list.

The solution is put together in a single comprehension:

```
[
    (min(vals), max(vals)) for vals in (
        list(x for key in grp.reshape(-1, grp.shape[-1]) for x in d[tuple(key)])
        for grp in indices
    )
]
```

The outer brackets indicate that a list is being constructed. `(min(vals), max(vals))` is a tuple of min and max of `vals`, and `vals` loops over the inner comprehension. The inner comprehension is a generator (with parentheses instead of brackets) generating the lists for each group in `indices`, as explained above.

Edit: you updated your question adding a `dtype` to indices, making it a structured array like this:

```
indices = np.array(
    [
        [[(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 3.75)], [(1.5, 1.0), (1.5, 3.75)]],
        [[(1.0, 2.5), (1.5, 1.0)], [(1.5, 2.5), (1.5, 3.75)]]
    ], dtype='float16,float16')
```

To counter that change and still make the solution work, you can simply work on an unstructured copy:

```
unstructured_indices = rf.structured_to_unstructured(indices)
for group in unstructured_indices:
    group = group.reshape(-1, group.shape[-1])
    values = list(x for key in group for x in d[tuple(key)])
    print(values)
```

And the solution becomes:

```
result = [
    (min(vals), max(vals)) for vals in (
        list(x for key in grp.reshape(-1, grp.shape[-1]) for x in d[tuple(key)])
        for grp in rf.structured_to_unstructured(indices)
    )
]
```

Comment: the code works on the input data I provided but not on my real code. I realized that I made a big mistake when I pasted the code. I forgot to make the array a structured array. When I use your code on the new data I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'writeable void-scalar'`

Comment: Mistakes get made - I've updated the answer to deal with that eventuality.